# How can I get exact user plus the user's exact posts in laravel from jwt token laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to get a list of a single user plus his/her post in another table, while passing the user jwt token in the header.

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim

    $user = auth()->user();
    $userid = User::where('id', $user->id);
    $return = UserResource::collection($userid);   
    return response()->json($return);


}
```

While doing it this way I get

```
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto() in file C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 50

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php(36): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::throwBadMethodCallException('mapInto')
```

But if I do it this way;

```
$user = auth()->user();
$userid = User::find($user);
$return = UserResource::collection($userid);   
return response()->json($return);
```

I get a response, but I get two users returned, instead of the exact user with the jwt token

When I return just **auth()->user()** I get the exact user of the jwt but without the post resource.

How can I get exact user plus the user's exact posts

Comment: Try `User::where('id', $user->id)->first();`

Comment: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\User::mapInto() in file 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 50

This is the response

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in the following snippet.

```
User::where('id', $user->id);
```

where is a syntactic sugar for calling where on a query builder, it therefor returns a query builder, to retrieve the user this way.

```
User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
```

Secondly a helper is made for this exact case called find(), you can call statically on model classes.

```
$user = User::find($user->id);
```

**EDIT**

```
$return = UserResource::collection($userid);
```

Expects a Collection, therefor change it to a single resource.

```
$return = new UserResource($userid);
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\User::mapInto() in file 
 
 
 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Forwa 
   rdsCalls.php on line 50